# extracting text between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Having a string like:

```
"*this* not that"
```

I can select **this**

```
\*(.*?)\*
```

but I'm not able to get only *this*.

what I am trying to achieve is to replace -this- by a new string. What's the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: Use `str = str.replace(/\*[^*]*\*/g, '*foobar*');`

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: `'"*this* not that"'.replace(/(\*(.*)\*)/gi, 'foo');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
"*this* not that".replace(/\*.*\*/,'*new_string*');
//"*new_string* not that"
```